# Unable to integrate keycloak with angular 8 using keycloak-angular

Tags: angular, authentication, authorization, angular8, keycloak

I want to integrate keycloak with angular 8.  I tried using https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-angular. I have installed it successfully but getting error `Cannot find namespace Keycloak` when i try to use it.

My goal is : 
1) From angular, when user is not logged In, user should be taken to Keycloak Login page.
2) After login, user should be taken back to angular app
3) From access token, angular app should be able to know user roles, controls routes which are accessible based on roles.

Please help with the solution. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to use keycloak.js from package.json and not from keycloak server